How to schedule an Airflow dag to run daily including today?
This code taken from the official documentation is supposed to work, but it doesn't, it omits today's execution. If in start_date I include yesterday's date if it is executed today, but in the interface it indicates me the date erroneously as if it had been executed yesterday.
import pendulum
from airflow.models.dag import DAG
from airflow.operators.empty import EmptyOperator
from airflow.decorators import task, dag
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator

with DAG(
    dag_id="example",
    schedule_interval='30 17 * * *',
    start_date=pendulum.datetime(2024, 12, 6, 17, 20, tz="Europe/Madrid"),  
    catchup=False,  
    tags=["example3"],
) as dag:

    def print_hello():
        print('hello')

    task1 = EmptyOperator(task_id="task1")
    task2 = EmptyOperator(task_id="task2")
    python_task = PythonOperator(
        task_id='my_python_task',
        python_callable=print_hello,
        op_kwargs={'key': 'value'}
    )
    task1 >> task2 >> python_task 



start_date I include yesterday's date if it is executed today

Do that.

in the interface it indicates me the date erroneously as if it had been executed yesterday.

That's normal / how it works. You can research what is "dag start time" and how it works. The dag with yesterdays date is for today. For example Why execution date is in the past when running a DAG with Airflow? .
Also, for "today" you can just run it manually for once and set start_date for any date in the past. Because cathup=False, it will only schedule itself for tomorrow.

I don't think you can say, “how it works”, if in the interface it says the dag will run today and in reality it means it will run tomorrow, then the software is badly made... Thanks anyway

Airflow is designed for backtesting, not for cron. Today you backtest data from yesterday. That's my understanding. Anyway, the time shown is the time when the dag has been scheduled, as I understand.
